# Command died with status 255 5.3.0- Email to SMS

Tags: php, postfix-mta, chron

I receive the following error when trying send emails via a distribution list e.g email to SMS:

```
This is the mail system at host email-to-sms-0x.xxx.com.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to 

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

The mail system

(expanded from
<7afc3e8f8de82@dist.test.com>): Command died with status
255: "/etc/mail/XXX.php". Command output: _

Final-Recipient: rfc822; dist-TEST-com@email-to-sms-02.test.com
Original-Recipient: rfc811;7afc3e8f8de82@dist.test.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.3.0
Diagnostic-Code: x-unix; _
```

The server uses postfix and I am unsure on how to proceed.
Would this be due to a php cronjob not executing or the permissions being incorrect?

Any help would be appreciated.
This is a Centos OS.
I have change some of the output to protect data.

Kind Regards
Ali G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the mail.log on email-to-sms-0x.xxx.com -- since Postfix doesn't disclose all information it obtained in the bounce.

It's probably a permission issue, yes :)